# Python - Type Checking Instances of Objects

Tags: python, class, object, instance, typechecking

I'm creating a class that emulates numeric types so as to be able to use basic arithmetic operators, like `+`, `-`, etc on instances of this class. However, I want to be able to handle the operation in different ways depending on what types the operands are. For instance, if I'm creating a class `foo_c` with `__add__()` as a function, then I want to be able to handle addition cases where one operand is of type `foo_c` and the other is of type `int` or `float` or `numpy.ndarray` (or `foo_c`).

The solution I want to implement is to have a collection of 'adder' functions to switch between based off of the operand type. The different functions are being assigned to a dictionary, as such:

```
class foo_c:

   ...

   self.addOps = { int: self.addScalar,
                   float: self.addScalar,
                   foo_c: self.addFoo }

   ...

   self.addScalar(self, sclr):
      ...

   self.addFoo(self, foo):
      ...

   self.__add__(self, operand):
      return self.addOps[type(operand)](operand)
```

The problem that I'm having is that I can't get the `type()` function to return the appropriate value to be used as a key for the dictionary. After creating an instance of the class as `foo = foo_c()`, the built-in function `type(foo)` returns `instance`instead of `foo_c`. I assume this is because I'm not creating the object in question; rather I am creating an instance of the object. I've used `foo.__class__` as well, but am getting `__main__.foo_c` as the returned class, which isn't right either...

I don't want to have to use lines of `isinstance()` checks, so is there a way to get `type()` to return the class as desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to have `foo_c` inherit from `object`, so you're getting an old-style class. Make it inherit from `object`:

```
class foo_c(object):
    ...
```

Comment: So, I gave it a try, and the problem I'm getting now is that the `type(foo)` is still outputting `__main__.foo_c` as its type, which it's type should be `foo_c` without `__main__.`

Comment: @S.Gamgee: No, that's correct. `__main__.foo_c` is the right class - it's the `foo_c` class defined in the `__main__` module.

Comment: Ok, I gotcha. I was operating in the IPython console and was executing `type(foo) == foo_c()` instead of `type(foo) == foo_c`. I'm good to go.